# How to use whereHas for ignoring empty array in eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I don't know how to ignore empty array values in my case. In my query I'm eager loading messages, but it gives me

```php
messages => []
```

with my query when deleted_from_sender is set to 1 (but I want to ignore it for pagination)

```php
static::with(['messages' => function ($q) use ($id) {

      return $q->where(function ($q) use ($id) {
                $q->where('user_id', $id)
                  ->where('deleted_from_sender', 0);
              })
               ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($id) {
                   $q->where('user_id', '!=', $id);
                   $q->where('deleted_from_receiver', 0);
               })->latest();       
}])->get();
```

I tried has and whereHas with the same query and whereNotNull, but no luck.

Comment: I feel bad posting this question, it should be easy...

Comment: what is `static` ? If it isn't a Model, then I don't see how this would work

Comment: In fact, if is a model he should change it, is not a good practice to name classes with reserved words

Comment: What you have to do is put the same query of `with` in the `whereHas`. This means that you have to use, `with` and `whereHas` together

Comment: @Derek Yes sorry it's a Model, like: Conversation::fetchInbox()

Comment: @bak87 see comment above. If you read in my post, I tried to use with and wherHas with the same query...